# How to obtain a list of strings from an XML file using Python's xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

All -

I am trying to parse the following, very simple XML document structure using

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <list>
       <file name="..." url="...">
       <words>
           word_1
           word_2
           ...
```

The problem I am having is that the XML contains a list of words that I would like to access as a list of strings ... and I simply can't seem to get it right. Here is what I have in terms of code so far:

```
import sys
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

for file in sys.argv[1:]:

    dom = parse( file )

    title = dom.getElementsByTagName( 'job_ad' )[0].getAttribute( 'title' )
    # This works 

    words = dom.getElementsByTagName( 'unigrams' )[0].childNodes[0]

    # This is NOT a list of strings ...
```

I would like to iterate over the data structure 'words' in this code. I know there are much more powerful XML modules available ... but for now I would like to solve this with the module shown.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance and kind regards -

Pat

Answer (score 1):

I assume words are listed under `words` nodes as plain text, in that case you just need to grab text from `words` node and split it e.g.

```
s="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <list>
       <file name="..." url="...">
       <words>
           word_1
           word_2
        </words>
       </file>
    </list>"""

import sys
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

dom = parseString(s)
words_text = dom.getElementsByTagName('words')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
words = words_text.split()
print words
```

output:

```
[u'word_1', u'word_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to 'xml.dom.minidom', you might want to checkout lxml  (http://lxml.de/)

The code would be:

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.parse( open(file) )
words = doc.findtext('words')
```

WHOOPS -- I see now the poster specifically requested the answer use 'xml.dom.minidom'. Sorry, we use lxml. You can disregard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in your XML doc, multiple `word_X` words are grouped inside an xml element. Since they are not different XML elements you cannot query like that. Instead you can use regular expression to parse a single element string 
For example: Assume you have `wordListAsSingleString` which contains (if you can query that):

```
       word_1
       word_2
```

`re.split('\s+', wordListAsSingleString)` will give you the list of words.

Answer (score 0):

If you want words to be a string, add .data to the end:

```
words = dom.getElementsByTagName( 'unigrams' )[0].childNodes[0].data
```